# Как отправить опрос повторно в telegram-боте?

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу отправить повторно обычный анонимный опрос пользователю бота.  Если постоянно вызывать метод `send_poll` - генерируется новый опрос, и количество голосов теряется, что для меня и есть проблемой. Пример:

`bot.send_poll(message.chat.id, 'Это опрос?', ['Да', 'Нет', 'Не знаю'])`

Я нашел один единый пример в интернете, где создается объект `telebot.types.Poll`. Точнее это не объект, а словарь, который отправляется с помощью аргумента `poll`

```
def send(message):
    poll = telebot.types.Poll(question='Это опрос?', options=['Да', 'Нет', 'Не знаю'])
    bot.send_poll(message.chat.id, poll=poll)
```

Но вот загвоздка в том, что в документации этого аргумента `poll` нет, и даже когда я запускаю код то получаю `TypeError: send_poll() got an unexpected keyword argument 'poll'`.

Вопрос - как мне передать объект/словарь, или `poll` в метод `send_poll` либо уже существующий `id`
опроса?

UPD. Отправить созданный опрос получилось, но результат все равно теряется. Кто-то знает, как правильно записывать результаты, чтобы статистика опроса отображалась в Telegram?

Comment: а если пересылать текущий опрос?

Comment: @D.Violet а это может быть хорошей альтернативой, попробую сегодня и отпишу о результатах)

Comment: @D.Violet, к сожалению не было времени проверить ранее. Пересылать сообщение не вариант- я получаю `Error code: 400`. Пробовал и идентификатор самого опроса и идентификатор сообщения - пока что безрезультатно(

Comment: @D.Violet, прошу прощения, ошибка была из-за того, что указал неверный идентификатор чата, с которого требуется переслать сообщение. Забираю свои слова обратно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы повторно отправить ранее созданный опрос - его можно переслать:

`bot.forward_message(message.chat.id, from_chat_id, message_id)`

Вместо `from_chat_id` - требуется указать ваш идентификатор чата (с какого чата будет пересылаться сообщение).

Вместо `message_id` требуется указать идентификатор сообщения (не `id` опроса).

Пример:

`bot.forward_message(message.chat.id, 123456789, 12345)`